# How can I stop React page to re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, use-state

I am using `fetch` to get data from API. I am using `useEffect` for page to stop rerender. But its not working

```
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

 if (load) {
    return <h2>Progress</h2>;
  }


  const fetchPicth = async () => {
    setLoad(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setPicth(data.pink);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     setLoad(false);
  }, [fetchPicth]);
```

Comment: Why do you want to stop a re-render? Setting state for example, will trigger a re-render.

Comment: I am already displaying data from json file using useState. Under the data I have button, on click of that button I fetch data from above API. When I click button, I do not want the data from json file to re-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using 2 approaches

1. Pass state in dependency array of useEffect

```
const [picth, setPicth] = useState([]);   // Initial state

 useEffect(() => {
    if (picth && picth.length !== 0) {   // Checks if data exists and length 
                                         //is greater than 0
      setLoad(false);                    // Set Loading to false
    }
  }, [picth]);


const fetchPicth = async () => {
    setLoad(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setPicth(data.pink);
  };
```

2. Check for the length, display Progress if there is no data. Display if data is present.

```
{picth.length === 0 && <div>Progress</div>}
      {picth.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {picth.map((book, index) => {
            return (
              <YourComponent></YourComponent>
            );
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fetchPicth` from the dependency array. If you'd like to set load to false you can do it like this:

```
const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);

 if (load) {
    return <h2>Progress</h2>;
  }


  const fetchPicth = async () => {
    setLoad(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setPicth(data.pink);
    setLoad(false)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     fetchPicth();
  }, []);
```

Using the code above will only fetch the data from the API only once i.e; when the component is mounted.

Comment: Does not work, whole page re-render with `Progress` text

Comment: Are you using the correct variable names? Shouldn't the setPcth be setPitch or something?

Comment: Yes, I checked that